# nginx reverse proxy in dmz with NAT for public internet

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to setup reverse proxy to make available an inter webapp (10.20.2.11) on the internet.  only https is allowed.

The issue is as soon as the reverse proxy (10.10.2.2) is NAT'd to 83.1.83.x (public ip) the reverse proxy stops loading webapp, the server even stops responding to ping and connections fails.
if the the NAT is disabled the reverse proxy starts working again.  The network engineer suspect the reverse proxy might be misconfigured.  This is the nginx config on centos7

## https only

server {

```
listen 443 ssl;
server_name webappserver.hk.;

ssl_certificate      /etc/pki/tls/certs/mycert.crt;
ssl_certificate_key  /etc/pki/tls/private/my.key;
access_log /var/log/nginx/webapp.access.log
error_log  /var/log/nginx/webapp.error.log;


location /{

    proxy_pass https://10.10.15.11; #ip of internal app

    proxy_redirect https://internalwebappserver.hk/ /; #url name of internal app

    proxy_http_version  1.1;
    proxy_cache_bypass  $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade           $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection        "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host              $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;




}
```

}

Comment: I prefer upsteams, but in your case, this is wrong `https:10.10.15.11//;`put slash in the wrong place

Comment: that slash was a typo, not in actual nginx config.  how would you do this in upstreams